# Run salt states twice with different pillar data?

Tags: salt-stack

I have set up pillar data for websites, e.g. web_root, virtualhost and mysql:

```
web_root:
  config_file: salt://some/path.conf
  key: some data
  directory_name: directoryA

virtualhost:
  config_file: salt://some/path.conf
  name: websiteA

mysql:
  database:
    - websiteA_db
```

These map to states for web_root, virtualhost and mysql (using formula).

I'd like to use have a minion run these states multiple times, using separate pillar data, e.g.

```
include:
    - apache
    - php
{% for instance in [instanceA, instanceB] -%}
    {% load pillar data /pillar/{{ instance }} -%}
    - web_root #run the state
    - virtualhost #run the state
    - mysql #run the state
{% endfor -%}
```

Is this possible? I know I can set up pillar data like so:

```
web_root:
  instanceA:
    config_file: salt://some/pathA.conf
    key: some data
    directory_name: directoryA
  instanceB:
    config_file: salt://some/pathB.conf
    key: some data
    directory_name: directoryB

virtualhost:
  instanceA:
    config_file: salt://some/pathA.conf
    name: websiteA
  instanceB:
    config_file: salt://some/pathB.conf
    name: websiteB

mysql:
  database:
    - websiteA_db
    - websiteB_db
```

But it means I have to add loops to each state file, making it less readable as well as use different syntax, e.g. for mysql which is a formula with set syntax requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this:

## Pillar Data

```
web_root:
  instances:
    A:
      - name: A
      - key: key_A_data
    B:
      - name: B
      - key: key_B_data
```

## State file

```
{% set names = salt['pillar.get']('web_root:instances') %}

apache:
  pkg.installed: []

{% for name in names %}
instance{{ name }}:
  - config_file: salt://some/path{{ name }}.conf
  - key: {{ key }}
  - directory_name: directory{{ name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then just do the same thing for the rest of your objects. This way you don't have to change your state file when you add objects to the pillar.